# How to split the start time and end time?

Tags: database, time

This question is about how to clean up the time data.
I am doing a database migration.

**Old system:**
For the time column, I have values such as:

```
9:30am - 12.30pm
9.30am - 12.30pm
9:30am-12.30pm
3pm to 7pm
3-9pm
1900-2000
1900h-2000h
etc etc...
```

**New System:**

```
Start time | End Time
0930 | 1230
0930 | 1230
0930 | 1230
1500 | 1900
1500 | 2100
1900 | 2000
1900 | 2000
```

**Problem:** How to efficiently convert the OLD values into NEW system where there are two columns with start and end time? (Or must I do it manually? The database has over 10000 records)

Comment: Writing a text processor in SQL is a daunting task. I'd really recommend doing it in whatever client language you're familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought perhaps it's better to clean the data first, but the database is so huge I could not possibly (well... I COULD... but...) clean the data record by record...

Answer (score 0):

Although the data is of inconsistent format it looks quite easy to convert to the required format, mostly with a series of simple find/replace.  For example in this order (or equivalent):

`to` > `-`
`.` > `:`
space > nothing
`a` > space`a`
`p` > space`p`
`h` > nothing

It is already more consistent:

```
9:30 am-12:30 pm
9:30 am-12:30 pm
9:30 am-12:30 pm
3 pm-7 pm
3-9 pm
1900-2000
1900-2000
```

Using Excel's Text to Columns with `-` as the delimited would then get to (in separate text columns):

```
9:30 am  12:30 pm
9:30 am  12:30 pm
9:30 am  12:30 pm
3 pm     7 pm
3        9 pm
1900     2000
1900     2000
```

Entering `1` somewhere in the spreadsheet and copying that cell before selecting cells containing `M` (with Find All and Ctrl+A) and then Paste Special, Multiply would coerce the selection into Time for formatting as as `hhmm`, to give:

```
     0930     1230
     0930     1230
     0930     1230
     1500     1900
3             2100
1900     2000
1900     2000
```

The likes of `3` would need some manual intervention (to guess whether AM or PM) but once that was addressed export as .csv should provide data ready for insertion.